# Monoidal properties of cotriple resolutions

Tags: ct.category-theory, homological-algebra

**edit:** it seems that there are irreparable problems with the question as phrased. I will have to think if it can be rephrased in a meaningful way...

(Co)triples can be used to construct resolutions in a wide variety of contexts. Thinking about this for a bit, I have observed the following:

Let $\mathcal{C}$ be a category with finite products, and write $\mathcal{C}'$ for the "discrete category" on $\mathcal{C}$, i.e. the category with the same objects but only identity morphisms. Then $\mathcal{C}'$ inherits a symmetric monoidal structure from the cartesian product of $\mathcal{C}$ (**edit: this is Not true, as pointed out on the comments**) and the canonical functor $\pi: \mathcal{C}' \to \mathcal{C}$ is (strong) symmetric monoidal. There is an induced adjunction $$\pi_\# : Pre(\mathcal{C}') \leftrightarrows Pre(\mathcal{C}): \pi^*$$
where $\pi_\#$ is the left left Kan extension and $\pi^*$ is pullback and $Pre(\mathcal{C})$ denotes the category of presheaves. The category $Pre(\mathcal{C})$ has products so is monoidal, and the category $Pre(\mathcal{C}')$ inherits a symmetric monoidal structure by Day convolution.

**Observation 1:** It appears to me that $\pi^*$, $\pi_\#$ are symmetric monoidal functors, and hence $G = \pi_\# \pi^*$ is a symmetric monoidal cotriple. ($\pi^*$ is monoidal by a direct computation, and $\pi_\#$ is monoidal because it is the cocontinuous extension of a monoidal functor and our monoidal products commute with colimits in both variables.)

**Observation 2:** Let $X \in \mathcal{C}$ and $A, B \in Pre(\mathcal{C})$, and suppose we are given a morphism $\alpha: X \times A \to B$. (Here and elsewhere, we shall write $X$ also for the presheaf it represents.) Then it seems that there is a canonically induced morphism $\alpha': X \times GA \to GB$. Indeed a morphism $X \times A \to B$ consists of a functorial family of morphisms $\alpha_T: A(T) \to B(X \times T)$ for $T \in \mathcal{C}$. On the other hand $GA = \coprod_{T \in \mathcal{C}} \coprod_{a \in A(T)} (T, a)$, where $(T, a)$ denotes an object canonically isomorphic to (the presheaf represented by) $T$ but with a "label" $a$. Then $\alpha'$ stares us right in the face: it is the morphism which sends $X \times (T, a)$ to $(X \times T, \alpha_T(a))$.

**Questions.**
Have these properties been systematically exposed? Is there a good way to think about (2)? Is it even true? I have defined something but obviously there are compatibilities which I have not checked...

**Motivation.** When using $G$ to construct resolutions, (1) means that our resolutions will be monoidal. (2) means that when resolving a product, and one of the factors is already resolved, it is actually ok (functoriality wise) to only resolve the other factor!

The only reference related to my questions I have found is this:

http://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0506624.pdf

Comment: I think you mean "discrete", not "chaotic". Chaotic means that each $\hom(x, y)$ is a singleton.

Comment: good to know - edited

Comment: As for observation 2: it's not clear to me what you mean by $X \times A$, unless you really mean $\hom(-, X) \times A$.

Comment: I don't understand why $\mathcal{C}'$ inherits a symmetric monoidal structure, the associativity and symmetry isomorphisms are barely ever identities. (And while associativity can be strictified, symmetry typically cannot.)

Comment: I think the case where they are identities is studied somewhere. For some reason, the term "strict symmetric monoidal category" springs to mind. Maybe the question makes sense in that context.

Comment: Also, the term "cotriple" is pretty archaic; nowadays most people say "comonad".